# Appcelerator Unable to locate cli executable

Tags: node.js, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I am using OSX El Capitain and have just downloaded Appcelerator Studio. After the installation I tried to run it and when I try to log in I receive this error message: Unable to locate CLI executable (print screen below). I have already installed NodeJs downloaded directly from Appcelerator website.

How could I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could have been an issue installing the the CLI depending on permissions. Appcelerator Studio installs node (if required), appcelerator CLI, Titanium CLI and others into a package underneath the AppceleratorStudio.app package. This is to ensure that it has those available.

I would recommend checking your permissions and potentially re-installing Appcelerator Studio from the link :

web.appcelerator.com

Additionally you could install the CLI's globally using the following commands:

```
sudo npm i -g appcelerator
sudo npm i -g titanium
sudo npm i -g alloy
```

Once they are installed, see about running studio again to see if you still have issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was the `/usr/local/bin` permission

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your CLI is not be installed properly that's why you get this error. So try to install the CLI manually through the terminal respectively

- sudo npm install -g appcelerator
- appc use latest
- appc setup
- sudo npm install -g alloy

Here's the documents link - 
https://web.appcelerator.com/product/cli

Then open the studio. Hope this helps.

Regards,
Appcelerator support.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the reason given by @bert-g, it might also because an old version of node (i.e. node 0.10) was installed instead of 0.12.

I was using nvm for node version control. When starting the app from application icon, it stuck at the same screenshot. Therefore I have tried to start the app from console (i.e. /Applications........./AppceleratorStudio) and it complains my node version should be 0.12. Used nvm install 0.12 and run from console again, it works!

Answer (score -1):

So whenever dev tools have problems with CLI things, the first thing I do is reinstall Xcode. Fixed everything almost every time.

This should unlink the libraries, uninstall, and remove Xcode

Go to Terminal and run:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo rm -rif ~/Applications/Xcode.app
```

Then go to the App Store and reinstall Xcode

Do make sure you are up to date, install the CLI tools from [HERE](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.10_for_Xcode_7.2/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.10_for_Xcode_7.2.dmg)

**You need both Xcode and the CLI tools**. I am not sure if the CLI tools are downloaded with Xcode so make sure by downloading both.

Please let me know if this works!

**Update**: Must have `Appcelerator CLI` installed and configured as well